# HtmlUnitDriver open url witch chrome cookie

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, kotlin, htmlunit-driver

(translated)
I use this code:

```
println("load cookies...")
val cookies: Set<DecryptedCookie> = ChromeBrowser().cookies as Set<DecryptedCookie>
println("load client...")
val browser = HtmlUnitDriver(true)

println("transfer cookies...")
for(cookie in cookies)
{
    println(cookie.domain)
    browser.manage().cookies.add(Cookie(cookie.name, cookie.decryptedValue, cookie.domain, cookie.path, cookie.expires))
}

println("load url...")
browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
browser.get("http://www.cyberforum.ru")
println(browser.pageSource)
```

But open link no loggedin. Import cookie with chrome sort of like successful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided. It was necessary to add through the method in Manage. Also can only used url and refresh^

```
val domain = "www.cyberforum.ru"
val site = "http://www.cyberforum.ru/"

val cookies = ChromeBrowser().getCookiesForDomain(domain) as Set<DecryptedCookie>
val browser = HtmlUnitDriver(true)

browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

browser.get(site)

for(cookie in cookies)
    browser.manage().addCookie(Cookie(cookie.name, cookie.decryptedValue, cookie.path, cookie.expires))

browser.get(site)
println(browser.pageSource)
```